# onItemSelected event fired only by user interaction

Tags: android, events, android-layout

I have a viewflipper that contains several layouts. I set an onItemSelected event for spinners that are present on every layout. There's a validation stage after clicking a button where I set the focus to the troubling component after I do a viewflipper.setDisplayedChild(layout_id) to go to the layout that contains it in the first place.

My problem is that setDisplayedChild is triggering the onItemSelected event for the spinners so it changes the focus to whatever component the validation sets the focus to, scrolling to that component the first time that layout is loaded.

Is there a way to set the trigger of such event only when the user explicitly fires it other than setting a flag for every spinner ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem a while back. What I did was before calling setDisplayedChild unregister the onItemSelected listener (set it to null) then do setDisplayedChild then re-register the onItemSelected listener.